# How to read from QFile? It shows that file not accessible

Tags: c++, qt, file, qt-creator

I've been trying to read .xml file using QFile. But qt creator can't even find it, but file exists inside project (also I tried to read it from another directory, not project's, it doesn't work, too). Debuger says file not accessible.

Here's my code:

```
QFile file("../info.xml");
if (file.exists())
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        qDebug(qPrintable("File exist"));
```

Comment: The problem is that that your path is being resolved against the *current working directory* and that is not what you think it is. You can either to supply an absolute path and use that, or work out what the current working directory actually is, and adjust your path accordingly.

Comment: @john thanks for you reply. I've tried to use full path before but the same result

Comment: Then it really must be some kind of access/permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but rather a list of what may have gone wrong.

- Check the file path :

```
    QFileInfo inf (file);
    qDebug() << inf.QFileInfo::path();
```

- Ensure that the file is in the right directory, i.e. in the same you have your `.exe` (`build-ProjectName-...`). You can check this by using `QDir::currentPath()`
- Check which `if` causes the problem : is it the first one which checks file existence or the second one that cannot open it ?
- I am not sure it is a good idea to use the `QFile::Text` for `.xml`  files.

In the end, I would do something like this :

```
QFile file("../info.xml");
QFileInfo inf (file);
qDebug() << "File path : "<< inf.QFileInfo::path() << Qt::endl;
qDebug() << "Current path : " << QDir::currentPath() << Qt::endl;
qDebug() << "Current path (expected) : " << QDir::currentPath() + "/info.xml" << Qt::endl;
if (file.exists()){
    qDebug() << "exists" << Qt::endl;
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)){qDebug() << "opened";}
    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've checked file path but it shows "../" in cmd and "." if I use just "info.qml". Also, I've tried to use full path and then it shows path, but file still doesn't work and debuger says "not accessible"

Comment: Did you try to use `QFile file(QDir::currentPath() + "/info.xml")` and then to put your file in `build-ProjectName-.../` ?